# Prevent firefox from auto-zooming website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this question has been asked widely but i've yet to find a solution to my question. 
I have a site (actually two), which has fixed layout for 1260px. When i enter the site with firefox, it basically fills the entire width of my browser. My screen resolution width is like 1900px, so it should only take part of it. Internet explorer works fine and shows the page "correctly". 
Now i have to first zoom-out twice with firefox.

Is there a way (html, css, jquery, anything) to tell firefox not to zoom-in? (or any other solution besides changing my firefox settings, since it won't affect other users)

Comment: have you tried using max-width:1260px on the main container in css?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` ???

Comment: Yeah, just tried that. Didn't help. Also, it looks more like it's not widening the container but rather "stretching" everything making it a bit blurry. in example; you would take 100x100 image and stretch it to 150x150px.

Comment: A. Wolff, that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: That has no effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: I found this and i have exactly the same problem:
https://support.mozilla.org/fi/questions/986007

If you could check the last message, which has pictures. I have no idea how could i fix this :/